# friendly_id, Update slug with history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am using `friendly_id` as follows:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, :use => [:slugged, :history]
end
```

I would like to be able to set the slug (i.e. be able to set a custom URL) without changing the title and maintaining old slugs in history.

Is there a straightforward way to do this using `friendly_id` or will I need to interact with the history table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I accomplished this by adding an instance attribute `url_seed`:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_for_url, :use => [:slugged, :history]

  attr_accessible :title, :url_seed
  attr_accessor :url_seed

  def slug_for_url
    self.url_seed.blank? ? self.title : self.url_seed
  end
end
```

Now, on save, if `url_seed` is set, `friendly_id` uses the custom URL text to set the URL.  Works like a charm :)